# ¿Como convertir lista python a Json?

Tags: python, json

Tengo una lista de objetos en python

```
body =  [['', 'semin', '2', 'Audiologia', 'Imagenologia', '0', 'particulares', '$0.00', '0', 'empresas', '$0.00', 'Si', '$0.00', '1/12/2021'], ['', 'semin', '2', 'Cardiologia', 'Imagenologia', '1', 'particulares', '$310.31', '0', 'empresas', '$0.00', 'Si', '$310.31', '1/12/2021'], ['', 'semin', '2', 'CLINICA', 'Imagenologia', '0', 'particulares', '$0.00', '0', 'empresas', '$0.00', 'Si', '$0.00', '1/12/2021'], ['', 'semin', '2', 'Densitometria', 'Imagenologia', '0', 'particulares', '$0.00', '0', 'empresas', '$0.00', 'Si', '$0.00', '1/12/2021']]
```

Tengo una función con la que intento pasar esa lista a un archivo Json, y lo logro, pero no divide los registros por comas, muestro el código:

```
def post_data(self):
    global body
    print(body)
    
    for rows in body:
        datos = (
            {
            'empresa': rows[1],
            'sucursal': rows[2],
            'departamento': rows[3],
            'area': rows[4],
            'numero_estudios_particular': rows[5],
            'tipo_particular': rows[6],
            'importe_particular': rows[7],
            'numero_estudios_empresa': rows[8],
            'tipo_empresa': rows[9],
            'importe_empresa': rows[10],
            'liquidado': rows[11],
            'total': rows[12],
            'date': rows[13],
            }
        )
```

Me guarda el archivo de la siguiente manera:

```
{'empresa': 'semin', 'sucursal': '2', 'departamento': 'Audiologia', 'area': 'Imagenologia', 'numero_estudios_particular': '0', 'tipo_particular': 'particulares', 'importe_particular': '$0.00', 'numero_estudios_empresa': '0', 'tipo_empresa': 'empresas', 'importe_empresa': '$0.00', 'liquidado': 'Si', 'total': '$0.00', 'date': '1/12/2021'}
{'empresa': 'semin', 'sucursal': '2', 'departamento': 'Cardiologia', 'area': 'Imagenologia', 'numero_estudios_particular': '1', 'tipo_particular': 'particulares', 'importe_particular': '$310.31', 'numero_estudios_empresa': '0', 'tipo_empresa': 'empresas', 'importe_empresa': '$0.00', 'liquidado': 'Si', 'total': '$310.31', 'date': '1/12/2021'}
{'empresa': 'semin', 'sucursal': '2', 'departamento': 'CLINICA', 'area': 'Imagenologia', 'numero_estudios_particular': '0', 'tipo_particular': 'particulares', 'importe_particular': '$0.00', 'numero_estudios_empresa': '0', 'tipo_empresa': 'empresas', 'importe_empresa': '$0.00', 'liquidado': 'Si', 'total': '$0.00', 'date': '1/12/2021'} {'empresa': 'semin', 'sucursal': '2', 'departamento': 'Densitometria', 'area': 'Imagenologia', 'numero_estudios_particular': '0', 'tipo_particular': 'particulares', 'importe_particular': '$0.00', 'numero_estudios_empresa': '0', 'tipo_empresa': 'empresas', 'importe_empresa': '$0.00', 'liquidado': 'Si', 'total': '$0.00', 'date': '1/12/2021'}
{'empresa': 'semin', 'sucursal': '2', 'departamento': 'Mastografia', 'area': 'Imagenologia', 'numero_estudios_particular': '0', 'tipo_particular': 'particulares', 'importe_particular': '$0.00', 'numero_estudios_empresa': '0', 'tipo_empresa': 'empresas', 'importe_empresa': '$0.00', 'liquidado': 'Si', 'total': '$0.00', 'date': '1/12/2021'}
```

Como se puede ver, no separa los registros por coma, y eso genera error a la hora que intento hacer un post a una API ¿Alguien tiene uno idea de como puedo solucionar esto, u otra forma de hacerlo?

Comment: es por que no usas el módulo `json`. Por cierto como estas escribiendo el archivo? Por favor añade más detalles y si te es posible lee [ask]